# Iteration over df rows to sum groups of items

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, iteration

I am new to coding. I looked for similar questions on this site, that helped me to come up with a working version of my code, but I need help with making it more professional.

I need help with iterating over rows of a data frame in pandas. What I want to do is to find same items (e.g. Groceries) in 'Description' column and total (sum) their values from 'Amount' column, and finally to write the result to a .csv file. The reason I am doing all this is to compile data for a bar graph I want to create based on those categories.

I was able to accomplish all that with the help of the following code, but that most likely is not very pythonic or efficient. What I did is that I used a print statement nested in an if statement to get category label (i) and amount to print to file. The issue is that I had to add a lot of things for the whole to work. First, I had to create an empty list to make sure that the if statement does not trigger .loc every time it sees a desired item in 'Description' column. Second, I am not sure if saving print statements is the best way to go here, as it appears very ersatz. It feels like I am a step away from using punch cards. In short, I would appreciate if someone could help me in making my code more up to standards.

'''

```
used_list = []
for i in df['Description']:
    if i in used_list:
        continue
    sys.stdout = open(file_to_hist, "a")
    print(i,',', df.loc[df['Description'] == i, 'Amount'].sum())
    used_list.append(i)
```

'''

I also tried a slightly different approach (save results directly into a df), but then I get NaN values all across the 'Amount' column and no other errors (exit code 0) to help me understand what is going on:

'''

```
used_list = []
df_hist_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Description', 'Amount'])
for i in df['Description']:
    if i in used_list:
        continue
    df_hist_data = df_hist_data.append({'Description' : i}, {'Amount' : df.loc[df['Description'] == i, 'Amount'].sum()})
    used_list.append(i)

print(df_hist_data)
```

'''

Comment: Hi, I originally read your post a bit quickly and tought you wished to sum groups of values. I understood that your problem was more with redundancy or rows with an identical ``description`` value. I have updated my answer, and hope it suits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select only rows that match a criteria with
`df[ a boolean matrix here ]`

When doing `df["a column name"]=="value"` you actually get a boolean matrix where rows where `"a column name"` == `"value"` are `True` and other are `False`

To sumarize this : Dataframe[Dataframe["Description"] == "banana"] is going to give you a view to a new dataframe where only rows matching your condition are kept. (original dataframe is not altered)

If you select column `"Amount"` of this dataframe and `.sum()` it, you have what you desired, in one line.
That's the typical `pandadorable` (equivalent of `pythonic` for pandas) way of doing conditionnal sums.

If require, select the rows of the dataframe where condition can take multiple values, use `.isin()` to get your boolean matrix

`Dataframe["Description"].isin(["banana","apple"])`

Then, when scanning all possible values of "Description" in your dataframe, use `.unique()` when generating your iterator.

And then you can finally append Series to your empty dataframe before saving it as csv.

Overal, we get the code :

```
import pandas as pd

Dataframe = pd.DataFrame([
    {"Description":"apple","Amount":15},
    {"Description":"banana","Amount":1},
    {"Description":"berry","Amount":155},
    {"Description":"banana","Amount":4}])

df_hist_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Description', 'Sum'])

for item in Dataframe["Description"].unique() :
    df_hist_data = df_hist_data.append( pd.Series( 
        { "Description" : item , 
         "Sum" : Dataframe[(Dataframe["Description"].isin([item]))]["Amount"].sum() }
        ), ignore_index=True )
```

```
OUT: 
>> 20
```

---

You can also do it even more pythonically, in one line with a list comprehension :

```
selector = "Description"
sum_on = "Amount"
new_df =  pd.DataFrame([  {selector : item , sum_on : df[(df[selector].isin([item]))][sum_on].sum() } for  item in df[selector].unique() ] )
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question exhaustively.